# How to extract first line that matches pattern from a file and if pattern doesn't exist print fixed output?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have a text file shown below:

```
Doc_A 123 abc
Doc_A 456 def
Doc_A 789 ghi
Doc_B 123 abc
Doc_B 456 def
Doc_C 123 abc
Doc_C 456 def
Doc_C 789 ghi
Doc_C 101 jkl
```

And a reference file

```
Doc_A
Doc_B
Doc_C
Doc_D
Doc_E
Doc_F
```

I want to extract the first line from text file that matches the name in the reference file and print that line and if there is no match print a certain fixed pattern as shown:

```
Doc_A 123 abc
Doc_B 123 abc
Doc_C 123 abc
Doc_D 10 20
Doc_E 10 20
Doc_F 10 20
```

I can use awk as shown below to print for matching pattern. How would I print patterns not found, certain fixed way as I require?

```
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = 0; } FNR != NR { for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i && a[i]++ == 0) { print $0; break; } }' \ref.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about deleting the entries from the lookup array as you match them, and then printing what's left at the end?

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
  $1 in a {print; delete a[$1]} 
  END {for (i in a) print i, "10 20"}
' ref.txt file.txt
Doc_A 123 abc
Doc_B 123 abc
Doc_C 123 abc
Doc_D 10 20
Doc_E 10 20
Doc_F 10 20
```

(Note that awk doesn't guarantee the order of array traversal - if that's an issue.)

## Explanation

While `NR==FNR`, we are processing the first named file (`ref.txt`): we create an array entry with its first (in this case, only) field as its index and then move to the `next` record. We don't need to assign a value to the array element.

Otherwise, we are processing the second named file (`file.txt`). We check whether its first column has a match in the array `a` that we constructed from the reference file, and print the record `$0` if it does. Then we delete the entry.

Deleting serves two purposes: it "uniquifies" the match, because next time we test `$1 in a` for the same `$1`, the answer will be false. It also means that after all lines of `file.txt` have been processed, any remaining elements in `a` have not been matched - we can print these in your "fixed" format in an `END` block.

Comment: array traversal is not an issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in detail, what exactly is happening here? I am unable to understand it fully.

Comment: @rkatraga I have added some explanation

Comment: This is great, I am just so amused by awk.

Answer (score 1):

Is awk a requirement for your task?  `grep` could also be used.

Your files appear to be space-delimited.  The solution below rests on the assumption that the fixed patterns in your reference file will never contain whitespace.

Let the text file be `file.txt`.  Let the reference file be `ref.txt`.

```
$ for P in $(cat ref.txt); do grep -m1 "^$P[[:blank:]]" file.txt || printf "%s 10 20\n" "$P"; done
Doc_A 123 abc
Doc_B 123 abc
Doc_C 123 abc
Doc_D 10 20
Doc_E 10 20
Doc_F 10 20
```

Comment: What is white space? can you elaborate.

Comment: [whitespace is a general term for characters like space, tab, CR, LF, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: So you mean its assuming there is no whitespace before pattern? Like in this case before Doc_A?

Also why is [[:blank:]] used after ^$P? what purpose does tab and space serve here? to recognize diff between Doc_A & Doc_AA? Can you clarify? Because I didn't think about it until I saw the code.

Thanks in advance, I am very new, and hopefully soon enough will pick up.

Comment: No, I mean no whitespace in `ref.txt`.  And yes, you are correct that the `[[:blank:]]` means that we require that there must be whitespace in `file.txt` after the pattern match, to avoid having `Doc_A` match `Doc_AA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways, like as for instance :

```
awk '
 NR == FNR && !($1 in a){a[$1]=$0}
 NR != FNR{print ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : $1" 10 20"}
' inp ref.txt


perl -lane '
  $h{$F[0]} = $_ unless exists $h{$F[0]}}{
  while ( <STDIN> ) {
     chomp;
     print(exists $h{$_} ? $h{$_} : qq<$_ 10 20>);
   }
' inp < ref.txt


while IFS= read -r a
do
   grep -m1 -F -- "$a" inp || echo "$a 10 20"
done < ref.txt
```

Results:

```
Doc_A 123 abc
Doc_B 123 abc
Doc_C 123 abc
Doc_D 10 20
Doc_E 10 20
Doc_F 10 20
```